# codeigniter: Remove index.php not working

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to remove index.php from url. But its not working!

Using ubuntu 12.04 ( LAMP).

CodeIgniter_2.1.2

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /cms1



        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
    </IfModule>
```

in config.php :

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; to $config['index_page'] = '';
```

Directory structure:

```
/var/www/cms1

->cms1
    ->application
    ->system
    ->user_guide
    ->index.php
    ->license.txt
    ->.htaccess
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it.
[permit changes in the .htaccess file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite)

Answer (score 3):

Htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

And in your applications/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.yourwebsite.com'; //url to your project
$config['index_page'] = ''; //Needs to be empty
```

Answer (score 0):

The project root-directory .htaccess file replace with below contains.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /your-project-directory-name/ 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```