# Remove index.php CI and mod_rewrite not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm trying to remove index.php on my URL (localhost). I've followed the steps from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url) and because it wasn't working, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523033/codeigniter-remove-index-php-not-working). What happen? What should I do?

Comment: please check with <?=phpinfo() ?> mod_rewried is enable or not? if not you have to enable in your apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux there are a few extra steps you need to take care of:

Use the a2enmod command to enable the module:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then restart Apache.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

mod_rewrite is now fully enabled.

But by default, Apache prohibits using an .htaccess file to apply rewrite rules, so first you need to allow changes to the file. Open the default Apache configuration file using nano or your favorite text editor.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Then add the following new block to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` so your configuration file looks like the following. Make sure that all blocks are properly indented.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

Save and close the file. To put these changes into effect, restart Apache.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Now, create an .htaccess file in the web root.

```
sudo nano /var/www/html/.htaccess
```

Add this line at the top of the new file to activate the rewrite engine. `/var/www/html/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Save the file and exit.

Not it should work just fine.

---

If you are using `xampp` it is supposed to be enabled by default.
On windows